# calls are made but no voice transferred to either sip client using asterisk and csipsimple

Tags: asterisk, sip, asteriskami, sip-server, csip-simple

I am using csipsimple as sip client and asterisk server to set up call. Calls are made between 2 sip clients but voice is not getting transferred.

Calls are made between 2 sip clients using AMI.

I can give my asterisk cli log.

Can anybody please give me some idea to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: please show your logs

Answer (score 0):

More info would be useful. First, make sure both clients are registered, and can use at least one common codec. In most cases, these aren't the problem. It's usually a NAT/Firewall issue. Are the two clients on the same subnet? Is there any firewall rules blocking the communication?

SIP signaling usually goes on udp:5060. But that seems working. Media is tricky. In each call, the ports for RTP audio changes, in the range specified in rtp.conf. This RTP traffic goes over UDP as well. By default it't 10000-20000.

If there is only routing done between the two endpoints, it should still be fine. NAT (Network Address Translation) is your main concern. Take a look at iptables, sip_nat_conntrack. To debug, use asterisk's sip set debug on command and look for the SIP headers and verify the correct IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you please tell me what info you need? I will provide you info that you need.